# i can't install package cached network image

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I am trying to create a new application with flutter, and i want to use package cached network image, but the package don't want to install in my pubspec.yaml

I tried flutter upgrade, and flutter doctor show no error

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+3
  cached_network_image: ^1.1.1
```

```sh
C:\fltr\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color packages get
Running "flutter pub get" in socialflutter_app...               
Error on line 1, column 1 of ..\..\..\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\cached_network_image-1.1.1\pubspec.yaml: Unexpected character.
  ╷




1 │                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  │ ^
  ╵
pub get failed (65)
Process finished with exit code 65
```

Comment: can you add the pubspec.yaml file ?

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+8
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.5
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  fluttertoast: ^3.1.0
  image_picker: ^0.6.1+3
  cached_network_image:^1.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try navigating to your Flutter folder, then to `pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\` and remove all `cached_network_image` folders.

[image]

then run `flutter packages get` again in your project.

Comment: soory iam just new in flutter, where exactly i can find pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\ in my flutter folder, and sorry for my english

Comment: @MahdiChafikCharif I have added a screenshot to the answer

Comment: i dont have .pub-cache folder in my flutter folder

Comment: if you didn't find it in the flutter folder, you can search for it here `AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org`

Comment: i found the folder and i did like you said but the problem has not been resolved

Comment: If that is your complete pubspec.yaml file from your Flutter project directory that you show in your question and in your follow up comment then it seems to be missing two lines at the top. 

It should start with:
name: <Name of your project>
description: A new Flutter project - whatever u want to put. 

Haven't tested this but could be the problem.